# Intermittent WCF Service failure

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have a WCF service that fails intermittently.  When it fails I can see from the svctraceviewer information that two separate threads are requesting 'connection information' at the same time.  One of the threads succeeds and the other fails with this error:  "An unexpected exception was encountered when using the WebContentTypeMapper."  The requests are identical except some values in the body of the POST, so I assume the real issue has to do with the collision while requesting 'connection information'.  I haven't been able to find any information on what the WCF runtime is doing during this 'connection information' request.

I should note that the client POSTs unencoded XML and uses an HTTP Content-Type header of application/xml so I have a custom binding to accept an xml stream.  I cannot change the way the client POSTs to my service.

Thoughts?

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.SAPCallbackHandler" behaviorConfiguration="">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" contract="SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.ISAPCallbackHandler" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" bindingConfiguration="customBindingHTTP" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost/service.svc/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="customBindingHTTP">
                <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.RawContentTypeMapper, SAPCallbackHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Code

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
[DataContract]
public class SAPCallbackHandler : ISAPCallbackHandler
{
    public string ParseIncomingXML(Stream incomingXML)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        if (contentType.Contains("text/xml") || contentType.Contains("application/xml"))
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw;
        }
        else
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISAPCallbackHandler
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string ParseIncomingXML(Stream incomingXML);
}
```

The 'connection information' trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>262168</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Level>8</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-04T16:52:26.3746976Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3992" ThreadID="7" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>TX-APP-J01</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
                    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectToIPEndpoint.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Connection information.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130280558217413872</AppDomain>
                    <Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager/4720237</Source>
                    <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord">
                        <LocalEndpoint>10.198.147.12:80</LocalEndpoint>
                        <RemoteEndpoint>163.231.6.69:24074</RemoteEndpoint>
                    </ExtendedData>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

The error trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>131075</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-04T16:52:26.4370984Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3992" ThreadID="7" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>TX-APP-J01</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
                    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130280558217413872</AppDomain>
                    <Exception>
                        <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                        <Message>An unexpected exception was encountered when using the WebContentTypeMapper.</Message>
                        <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.TryGetContentTypeMapping(String contentType, WebContentFormat&amp;amp; format)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.IsContentTypeSupported(String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ValidateContentType()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An unexpected exception was encountered when using the WebContentTypeMapper. ---&amp;gt; System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\sapqueueservice\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.RawContentTypeMapper.GetMessageFormatForContentType(String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.TryGetContentTypeMapping(String contentType, WebContentFormat&amp;amp; format)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The process cannot access the file 'c:\sapqueueservice\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.RawContentTypeMapper.GetMessageFormatForContentType(String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.TryGetContentTypeMapping(String contentType, WebContentFormat&amp;amp; format)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\sapqueueservice\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at SAPCallbackHandlerNamespace.RawContentTypeMapper.GetMessageFormatForContentType(String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncoderFactory.WebMessageEncoder.TryGetContentTypeMapping(String contentType, WebContentFormat&amp;amp; format)</ExceptionString>
                        </InnerException>
                    </Exception>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Service running on: IIS 7.5, .NET 4.5, Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message stands out:

**System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\sapqueueservice\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.**

Looks like a process is locking this file.

Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out which process has a handle on it.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem.  Don't know how I missed it.

Even though I wasn't actually writing any log lines, the 'using' statement was holding the resource and resulting in the contention.

Thanks!